# Help needed with Facebooks and TYPO3

Tags: facebook, content-management-system, typo3

I have the following problem and  I hope you can give me your precious support.

Can you please tell my why if i try to share on facebook the following page

http://www.bioversityinternational.org/index.php?id=4087
it works

while with this one doesn't. 
http://www.bioversityinternational.org/index.php?id=4319

Both are on the same server, same application ( TYPO3 ) behind the same firewall.
I'm not a developer so sorry if this could be obvious for you.
Thank you
C.

Comment: Are you sure they are both served via typo3? the second one doesn't have the usual TYPO3 header code (which by the way is a violation of the TYPO3 license if it's being served via TYPO3). How are you calling facebook from that page? I couldn't find a share link.

Answer (score 0):

Both work fine when I post them to my facebook profile. What exactly is or was the error?

Generally Facebook creates posts like that:

- The title is taken from the < title >
  tag in the < head > part of the source
  code
- Thumbnails are generated from
  the < img > tags, first tag = first
  thumbnail.
- First < p > Tag is used for    for the
  content summary.